# Cannot update BIOS correctly

Tags: windows, bios, updates, black-screen-of-death

I own an `Alienware 2017r3 with BIOS [Alienware 1.2.14, 02/06/2016]`.

Support Assist says that I should update to `1.3.12`, [but by reading online](https://www.dell.com/support/article/it/it/itdhs1/sln148359/how-to-run-a-bios-update-on-an-alienware-computer?lang=en) I found out that the proper path for this should be:

```
1.2.15 -> 1.3.6 -> 1.3.10 -> 1.3.12
```

I begun with `1.2.15` to no avail. After I run the .exe, the laptop reboots but then remains stuck in a black screen.
After a long time, I just force-shut it off. After turning it on again, everything works fine but the BIOS version is still `1.2.14`.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That page doesn't have any information about doing incremental updates. It's rather unusual for BIOS updates to begin with as usually you get a complete image.

Comment: BIOS updates are rarely done incrementally. Why are you updating the BIOS? This is typically done to fix a problem or get a needed feature - not just because. If you mess this up you may have a dead motherboard on your hands.

Comment: @Seth It does, there's a yellow warning box in the middle of the page: https://imgur.com/a/rXbtq

Comment: @Appleoddity I thought it would be better to always have the lastest version. Also, from the task manager I see that the BIOS startup time is 19sec, whereas my friends with the lastest BIOS get 4 seconds. I actually used to get 5 seconds give or take, but recently this has changed for no apparent reason.